# is it really fixed to solve the missing archive updates or upgrades?

Tags: apt, updates

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing? and how to use the --fix-missing.

I tried something, please check this also and tell me if it is really fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to resolve this is use `sudo apt update` > `sudo apt-get update` > `sudo apt upgrade` this resolved my issue.

Comment: `suduo apt update` and `sudo apt-get update` does the same thing - only one is needed.